# AVX intrinsics for tiled matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, matrix, optimization, intrinsics, avx

I was trying to use AVX512 intrinsics to vectorize my loop of matrix multiplication (tiled). I used __mm256d as variables to store intermediate results and store them in my results. However, somehow this triggers memory corruption. I've got no hint why this is the case, as the non-AVX version works fine. Also, another weird thing is that tile sizes somehow affects the result now.

The matrix structs are attached in the following code section. The function takes two matrix pointers, m1 and m2 and an integer for tileSize.Thanks for @harold's feedback, I've now replaced the _mm256_load_pd for matrix m1 with broadcast. However, the memory corrupution problem still persist. I've also attached the output of memory corruption below

```c
__m256d rResult rm1, rm2, rmult;


    for (int bi = 0; bi < result->row; bi += tileSize) {
         for (int bj = 0; bj < result->col; bj += tileSize) {
             for (int bk = 0; bk < m1->col; bk += tileSize) {
                 for (int i = 0; i < tileSize; i++ ) {
                     for (int j = 0; j < tileSize; j+=4) {
                         rResult = _mm256_setzero_pd();
                         for (int k = 0; k < tileSize; k++) {

                            //  result->val[bi+i][bj+j] += m1.val[bi+i][bk+k]*m2.val[bk+k][bj+j];


                             rm1 = _mm256_broadcast_pd((__m128d const *) &m1->val[bi+i][bk+k]);
                             rm2 = _mm256_load_pd(&m2->val[bk+k][bj+j]);
                             rmult = _mm256_mul_pd(rm1,rm2);
                             rResult = _mm256_add_pd(rResult,rmult);
                             _mm256_store_pd(&result->val[bi+i][bj+j],rResult);
                         }
                     }  
                 }
             }
         }
     }
return result;
```

```
*** Error in `./matrix': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001880910 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x81609)[0x2b04a26d0609]
./matrix[0x4016cc]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x2b04a2671495]
./matrix[0x400e29]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 00:2c 6981358608                         /home/matrix
0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 00:2c 6981358608                         /home/matrix
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 00:2c 6981358608                         /home/matrix
01880000-018a1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
2b04a1f13000-2b04a1f35000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 12900                      /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
2b04a1f35000-2b04a1f3a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2b04a1f4e000-2b04a1f52000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2b04a2134000-2b04a2135000 r--p 00021000 00:16 12900                      /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
2b04a2135000-2b04a2136000 rw-p 00022000 00:16 12900                      /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
2b04a2136000-2b04a2137000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2b04a2137000-2b04a2238000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 13188                      /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
2b04a2238000-2b04a2437000 ---p 00101000 00:16 13188                      /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
2b04a2437000-2b04a2438000 r--p 00100000 00:16 13188                      /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
2b04a2438000-2b04a2439000 rw-p 00101000 00:16 13188                      /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
2b04a2439000-2b04a244e000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 12867                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
2b04a244e000-2b04a264d000 ---p 00015000 00:16 12867                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
2b04a264d000-2b04a264e000 r--p 00014000 00:16 12867                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
2b04a264e000-2b04a264f000 rw-p 00015000 00:16 12867                      /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
2b04a264f000-2b04a2811000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 13172                      /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
2b04a2811000-2b04a2a11000 ---p 001c2000 00:16 13172                      /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
2b04a2a11000-2b04a2a15000 r--p 001c2000 00:16 13172                      /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
2b04a2a15000-2b04a2a17000 rw-p 001c6000 00:16 13172                      /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
2b04a2a17000-2b04a2a1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2b04a2a1c000-2b04a2a1e000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 13184                      /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
2b04a2a1e000-2b04a2c1e000 ---p 00002000 00:16 13184                      /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
2b04a2c1e000-2b04a2c1f000 r--p 00002000 00:16 13184                      /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
2b04a2c1f000-2b04a2c20000 rw-p 00003000 00:16 13184                      /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
2b04a4000000-2b04a4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
2b04a4021000-2b04a8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffc8448e000-7ffc844b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc845ed000-7ffc845ef000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Comment: Besides not providing a [mre], what you are computing is only vaguely related to  a matrix product (e.g., you never reset `rResult` back to zero, but you overwrite `result->val[bi+i][bj+j]` multiple times) -- I suggest to first implement a scalar variant for comparison. The reason for your "memory corruption" is probably that your memory is not aligned. Try `_mm256_loadu_pd` and `_mm256_storeu_pd` (or better, make sure that your memory is aligned).

Comment: Why would you broadcast a *pair* of `double`s, instead of `_mm256_broadcast_sd` or `_mm256_set1_pd()`?  Doesn't make much sense.  And also, did you read my answer?  I still think it probably explains the memory corruption, unless your matrix sizes are multiples of the tile width.  Harold's answer was just talking about the math correctness problem, separate from the array bounds problems.

Comment: The code you posted does not contain any call to `free()`, i.e., the cause of your (current) memory corruption lies elsewhere. Provide a [mre]! Read that link to see how and why!

Comment: @chtz In fact, there isn't one free function. I guess the memory corruption is the pointers were overflown somewhere.

Comment: Are you intentionally ignoring my request for a MRE? Are you aware that C++ might call `free()` e.g. via a `delete` operator or the destructor of a container?

Answer (score 3):

That code loads a small row vector from m1 and a small row vector from m2 and multiplies them, which is not how matrix multiplication works, I assume it's direct vectorization of the identical scalar loop. You can use a broadcast-load from m1, that way the product with the row vector from m2 results in a row vector of the result which is convenient (the other way around, broadcasting from m2, you get a column vector of the result which is tricky to store - unless of course you use the column-major matrix layout).

Never resetting `rResult` is also wrong, and takes extra care when using tiling, because the tiling means that individual results are put aside and then picked up again later. It's convenient to implement `C += A*B` because then you don't have to distinguish between the second time that a result is worked on (loading `rResult` back out of the result matrix) and the first time that a result is worked on (either zeroing the accumulator, or if you implement `C += A*B`, then it's also just loading it out of the result).

There are some performance bugs,

- Using one accumulator. This limits the inner loop to run once every 4 cycles (Skylake) in the long term, because of the loop-carried dependency through the addition (or FMA). There should be 2 FMAs per cycle but that way there would be one FMA every 4 cycles, 1/8th speed.
- Using a 2:1 load-to-FMA ratio (assuming the mul+add is contracted), it needs to be 1:1 or better to avoid getting bottlenecked by load throughput. A 2:1 ratio is limited to half speed.

The solution for both of them is multiplying a small column vector from m1 with a small row vector from m2 in the inner loop, summing into a small *matrix* of accumulators rather than just one of them. For example if you use a 3x16 region (3x4 vectors, with a vector length of 4 and the vectors corresponding to loads from m2, from m1 you would do broadcast-loads), then there are 12 accumulators, and therefore 12 independent dependency chains: enough to hide the high latency-throughput product of FMA (2 per cycle, but 4 cycles long on Skylake, so you need *at least* 8 independent chains, and at least 10 on Haswell). It also means there are 7 loads and 12 FMAs in the inner loop, even better than 1:1, it can even support Turbo frequencies without overclocking the cache.

I would also like to note that setting the tile size the same in every dimension is not necessarily the best. Maybe it is, but probably not, the dimensions do act a little differently.

More advanced performance issue,

- Not re-packing tiles. This means tiles will span more pages than necessary, which hurts the effectiveness of the TLB. You can easily get into a situation where your tiles fit in the cache, but are spread over too many pages to fit in the TLB. TLB thrashing is not good.

Using asymmetric tile sizes you can arrange for either m1 tiles or m2 tiles to be TLB-friendly, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Lol, I thought the OP's code looked surprisingly simple.  I wondered if maybe one of their inputs was already transposed, but I just posted a quick answer about the loop bounds and didn't take a serious look at what it was actually doing.

Comment: @harold Thanks for your detailed explanation. I've read a bit more about load and now replaced _mm256_load for matrix m1. Indeed, I was still thinking in scalar load and store in the matrix multiplication. I've edited my code section, would you please take another look and give me some more feedback? One problem I have is that as the tile size changes, I can't get consistent results and it causes memory corruption in matrix free() function, which cause the program to abort.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance, normally you want one contiguous chunk of memory, not an array of pointers to rows.

Anyway, you're probably reading off the end of a row if your tile size isn't a multiple of 4 doubles per vector.  Or if your rows or cols aren't a multiple of the tile size, then you need to stop after the last *full* tile, and write cleanup code for the end.

e.g. `bi < result->row - (tileSize-1)` for the outer loops

If your tile size isn't a multiple of 4, then you'd also need `i < tileSize-3`.  But hopefully you are doing power-of-2 loop tiling / cache blocking.  But you'd want a `size - 3` boundary for vector cleanup in a partial tile.  Then probably scalar cleanup for the last few elements.  (Or if you can use an unaligned final vector that ends at the end of a row, that can work, maybe with masked loads/stores.  But trickier for matmul than for algorithms that just make a single pass.)

Comment: Thanks! Although it still causes memory corruption after I placed the new boundaries for the outer loop. I assumed the boundaries were correct as they worked fine for my scalar versions.

Comment: @HerrGünther: yeah, easy to forget to fix loop bounds when vectorizing.  But to understand why, remember that vectorizing is a kind of unrolling: each iteration unconditionally does 4 or 8 or whatever array elements.  You unroll by 4 and then do those 4 iterations with one SIMD vector.  And the highest `i` value where it's safe to start an unrolled iteration is one where `i+3` is the last element you're supposed to touch.  Anyway, if that still didn't fix the bug, then double-check your other loops (e.g. the column loops) to make sure you didn't miss any.  Also there's tools like valgrind.